# Angular with Webpack - Bootstrap included in vendor bundle but not working

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, webpack

I have bootstrap included into my vendor.js bundle, as evident from snapshot below,
[image]

Inspecting DOM, i can see that bootstrap classes are also being applied, as evident from snapshot below,

[image]

Still, the dropdown component doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: And there are no errors in developer console in browser

Comment: styles aren't there or functionality is missing?

Comment: @JayDeeEss styles are there, functionality is missing. With bs dropdown under inspection in dev-tools, i don't see anything whatsoever happen when i click it

Comment: Please include your component.ts file in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like bootstrap.css file is missing?